# AVAsset Saving video in iOS with image overlay ruins video

Tags: ios, video, uiimage, avasset

I'm trying to merge an image overlay and a video into a new video file. This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)mergeVideoUrl:(NSURL *)videoURL andOverlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    // Create an AVURLAsset
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                                   ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                     error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];

    // Get our image layer
    CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
    aLayer.contents = (id)overlayImage.CGImage;
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    aLayer.opacity = 1.0;

    // Sort the layer order
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

    // Create the composition and add the instructions to insert the layer
    AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    // Instruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    // Export
    AVAssetExportSession *assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;

    NSString* videoName = @"mynewwatermarkedvideo.mov";

    NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
    NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
    }

    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {
         //FINALIZATION CODE HERE
         NSLog(@"DONE: %@", exportUrl);
     }];
}
```

The problem is that it screws up the video. Any idea why?
I have a feeling the video frame size might have something to do with it or the aspect ratio as if I set a size of `(2000,2000)`, it seems to work ok but with a lot of black edges.

[image]

EDIT-----
It seems that if I set `CGSize videoSize` to a ratio of 2/3 e.g.`320x480` or `1280x1920` then it works, however the resulting video has a black bar down the right hand side. Why would `[clipVideoTrack naturalSize]` report a size of `1080x1920` but it screws up unless I use `1280x1920`? I think it might be a transform/crop issue?

EDIT2-----
Changing the `AVAssetExportSession` presetName between `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`, `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` & `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` results in different sized videos. So I think that is overriding the output video frame size somehow.

Comment: Why a vote to close?

Comment: What size is your overlay ?

Comment: The current overlay is `750x1334` but that's not the issue, as using some text instead of the image gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];
```

This gives you the dimensions of the recording, but you need to look at the track's `prefferedTransform` to find the orientation of the recording. You might well find that the video width is actually the `naturalSize` 'height' depending on how the device was held during recording.

I see you set it on the composition, but you need to check it in order to assign the correct frames to your `CALayers`

Comment: That makes sense. The `preferredTransform` transform of the video track shows as `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`i'm not sure how to check this for flipping the x/y coords.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is the issue now, as flipping the height/width in the `videoLayer.frame` gives the same result but only half a screen of blurry video.

Comment: Flipping the x/y of `videoComp.renderSize` is the only way I get video that's not messed up, however it gives me a landscape video instead of portrait yet the video itself is the correct orientation.

Comment: Are you making sure you set a transform on your AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction? Setting this to either the clips prefferedTransform or creating a portrait transform might help

Comment: I've tried adding `[layerInstruction setTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform] atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 30)];`